# Bootstrap: centralize row elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/3014866) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29941318/3014866) answers. But I didn't succeed:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="btn-group-vertical">
          <div class="row row-eq-height" style="overflow: hidden">
               <div class="col-sm-6" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">hello</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;">
                    <span class="label label-success"
                                     style="font-size: small; vertical-align: iddle;">World</span>
                </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want `World` be centralized by `hello` element. How could I make it happen?

Comment: try : flex css3 to display multiple alignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Bootstrap `form-inline`.. no extra CSS needed.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
         <button class="btn btn-default">hello</button>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <span class="label label-success">World</span>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**http://bootply.com/ZjjHreVVjA**

P.S. - `btn-group-vertical` is for [vertical button groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-vertical), not vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/94T9XqF3ss):

```
 .row-eq-height{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple mistakes in your code:

First, you surrounded the btn-group with the columns, hence it broke the columns, considering that if you drew a black line around "btn-group", it would only include the contours outside the button (not the entire width of the row). You will have to put btn-group just outside the button (not surround columns) in the future.

i.e.:

```
<div class = "btn-group"> <button class = "btn btn-default"> </button> <div>
```

I've altered your bootstrap classes to make each column worth 3 cols, and "pushed" the second two over to the right. This should center given a certain size (for larger sizes, you would have to add more column classes with push classes)

```
             <div class="row row-eq-height" style="overflow:hidden">
                  <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: -99999px;
     padding-bottom: 99999px;">
                       <button class="btn btn-default">hello</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-2" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-bottom: -99999px;
     padding-bottom: 99999px;">
                       <span class="label label-success"
                                        style="font-size: small; vertical-align: iddle;">World</span>
                   </div>
             </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and search for offset classes. each row has 12 columns. If you give a `div` the class `col-sm-6` that div takes 6 out of 12 columns, you have 6 remaining (empty) columns. To center this `div` you'd offset it by the remainder divided by 2: 3 (6 / 2 = 3). So if you'd add `col-sm-offset-3` to said `div` it'll be in the center.

**How this applies to your question:**
Put both buttons in one `div` and center it using the above method.

**Edit**

You asked how to center a row element, you shouldn't. Inside the `.row` element add a `.container` element and inside of that `.container` add your columns: `col-device-size`.